# Creating an Excel Chart in C# Using Data From Non-Adjacent Columns

Tags: c#, excel, charts, excel-interop

I need to create a chart using two ranges from two non-adjacent columns and define within the code which range will be taken to X Axis and to Y Axis.

For example: for the two ranges `M3:M15` and `K3:K15` I need X axis values to be from `K3` to `K15`, and Y axis values to be from `M3` to `M15`.

I have a code creating a chart from two adjacent columns :

```
string start_chart_values = "M3";
int stop_chart_line_calc = 1 + num_of_rows_to_copy;
string stop_chart_values = "L" + stop_chart_line_calc.ToString();
double chart_location = stop_chart_line_calc * 12;
Excel.Range chartRange;

Excel.ChartObjects xlCharts = (Excel.ChartObjects)xlWorkSheet.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
Excel.ChartObject myChart = (Excel.ChartObject)xlCharts.Add(2, chart_location, 300, 250);
Excel.Chart chartPage = myChart.Chart;
Excel.Axis yAxis = chartPage.Axes(Excel.XlAxisType.xlValue, Excel.XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
yAxis.ScaleType = Excel.XlScaleType.xlScaleLogarithmic;

chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range(start_chart_values, stop_chart_values);
chartPage.SetSourceData(chartRange);
chartPage.ChartType = Excel.XlChartType.xlXYScatterSmooth;
chartPage.ChartWizard(Source: chartRange, Title: "Recommended Blood Pressure", CategoryTitle: "Students Age", ValueTitle: "Blood Pressure");
```

Unfortunately this code is not good enough because I need the ability to choose myself the values of X axis and Y axis within the code.

How can I Change the code so that I will be able to define within the code which range will be taken to X Axis and to Y Axis?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the X and Y values for each series manually to accomplish this, as the chart and series initialization methods do not include this functionality. Note that you will want to ensure that your initial selection only encompasses your Y-Values, as selecting the entire range would end up creating multiple series.

Here is an example of how you could modify your code to achieve this:

```
Excel.Series series = chartPage.SeriesCollection().Add(xlWorkSheet.Range["M3:M15"]);
series.XValues = xlWorkSheet.Range["K3:K15"];
```

This can also be used to create charts with values split across columns or rows. For example, to create a chart like the following, with X-Values split across multiple columns:

[image: Chart with x-values from 2 columns]

You could use the following code:

```
Excel.ChartObject chartObject = sheet.ChartObjects().Add(0, 0, 500, 250);

Excel.Series series = chartObject.Chart.SeriesCollection().Add(xlWorkSheet.Range["C2:C7"]);
series.XValues = xlWorkSheet.Range["A2:A4,B2:B4"];
```